# Cross filtering between two facts and common dimension tables in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following scenario.

I have two fact tables [FactA and FactB]. FactA and FactB contains 9 common dimensions and their own measures. I am trying to pull the measures from both fact tables into a table visualization and trying to filter the results using common dimensions. It works for the measure pulled from one fact table and not for the other fact table. I tried to set the cross filter direction to both on all the relationships between common dimensions and facts. I was able to set the cross filter for one dimension table, when I am trying to set the same for remaining dimensions, I am getting an warning that Power BI desktop allows only one filtering path between tables in a data model.

Also I tried to see if the cross filtering is working fine for the one dimension that I enabled cross filtering by pulling that dimension key and measures from both facts. But it didn't change anything.

Is there a way I can pull measures from both facts and have it filtered by common dimension values? Please share your thoughts and suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Wrong number? No number? Error? I guess all of the filtering directions are currently from dimensions to facts?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, I missed to link one of  the dimension tables to one fact table. I linked it and enabled the cross filtering, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have joined all the dimension tables to both fact tables. All dimension tables have 1 to many relationships with Fact tables. I have hidden all the dimension columns in report view for both fact tables. I just have measures visible on both Facts. In the visualization tab, I have pulled the measures from fact tables and dimension columns from dimension tables. It fixed the issue.

Also I learnt that, you can derive a new measure using other measures available in different fact tables.