# power bi scatter plot with customized color points and cross-filtering cards

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, star-schema

I created two dim tables Price and Km and made a one to many relationship with each of FactTAB1 and FactTAB2

1. I've not found on the web and in the sw setting the possibility to show **color of the points** in a scatterplot with axis Price and Km **based on the entry being from FactTAB1 or FactTAB2** (it requires a always a field). I understand I could join the 2 TABs and add a column to use as legend with values the name of the Tab of that entry but there are solutions less memory intensive than duplicating all the data?
2. If I **select a datapoint** in the plot it will **only change the card related to km and price**, but not the other (Brand/Model/etc) even if I have created dim tables with 1:many relationship even for those dimensions.
   I understand it is filtering only the two dims putted on the axis but there is any way to make it filter also the other dims. At the moment i can only reproduce that behaviour with the top-right multirows card but can't control too much the appearance, it's just a workaround but would learn a better way to make this work with single cards.
3. I've made a Photo dim table with this DAX code `Foto = DISTINCT (UNION (SELECTCOLUMNS (autoscout24Data,"Foto",autoscout24Data[Foto]),SELECTCOLUMNS ('automobile-itData',"Foto",'automobile-itData'[Foto])))`. It should select the unique values from the two Fact Tables and it shows me no duplicate, but when I try to build the relationship between this new dim table and the two Fact Tables **it doesn't allow me a 1:many relationship** and can't understand why. At all.

Thanks in advance

[image: The two dim tables]
[image: The relationship model]
[image: The scatterplot and the cards]

I tried many workaround and google search and sw settings alternative. But not find a fix to these 3 problems.
[Cross filtering between two facts and common dimension tables in Power BI Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071597/cross-filtering-between-two-facts-and-common-dimension-tables-in-power-bi-deskto) this seems related (cross-filtering) but more 'elementary', I've already two dims cross-filtering two tables but can't make the plot cross-filter even the for the other dims. I've tried to create measures with SELECTEDVALUE Dax code but hasn't fixed in my case when I put those measures on the single cards (except for Km and Price).